# Extension Type "File" execute scriptfile tag in manifest

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, custom-component

I have declared a XML manifest file for my extension of type file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="file" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
    <name>os_mp</name>
...
...
    <scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
...
...
</extension>
```

The script file is like this:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class os_mpInstallerScript
{
    public function postflight($type, $parent)
    {
        echo '<h1>' . $type . '</h1>';

        var_dump($type);
        var_dump($parent);
    }
}
```

But the code of the scrip file doesn't seem to get executed.

Please advise!

Comment: What makes you say that the postflight isn't executed? If you're using the installer in J3 then you wouldn't see the var_dump on the screen if that's what you mean. Cause it's using an ajax file uploader and it redirects after processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. I have miswritten the class name of the installer script

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class os_mpInstallerScript
{
    public function postflight($type, $parent)
    {
        echo '<h1>' . $type . '</h1>';

        var_dump($type);
        var_dump($parent);
    }
}
```

To find the correct calss name that joomla installer expected, I debugged the setupScriptfile member function of JInstallerAdapter. The file is located at `libraries/cms/installer/adapter`